# how to set pubsub node to send normal messages instead of headline in smack

Tags: publish-subscribe, ejabberd, smack

I am trying to set notification-type of pubsub node to "normal" instead of "headline". I know there is attribute in xep-060 called "pubsub#notification_type" but when I try to set that attribute using configuration form at the time of creation, I get error. below is my code snippet

```
ConfigureForm form = new ConfigureForm(DataForm.Type.submit);
form.setAccessModel(AccessModel.open);
form.setDeliverPayloads(true);
form.setNotifyRetract(true);
form.setPersistentItems(false);
form.setPublishModel(PublishModel.open);
form.setAnswer("pubsub#notification_type", "normal");
node = (LeafNode)pubSubMgr.createNode(bean.getGroupId(), form);
```

Can anyone please guide me how to set notification-type while creating node?

Comment: Please, share more details: What is the actual XMPP packet being send ? What is the error returned by the server ?

Comment: Remond, unfortunately, there wasn't any error but on further research I found that, I need to set answer on answer form. So instead of doing form.setanswer, I should do answerform=form.getAnswerForm() and then set all required values in it.